# Exception when deserializing a Json string to an user defined object

Tags: c#, .net, json, uwp

I'm having a problem that raises an exception `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException` in Newtonsoft.Json.dll when trying to deserialize an Json formatted string to an user defined object. The string that I'm reading from the file has been written before using the same object.

This is the code of deserielization (exception at the last line).

```
 storageFile   = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(filePath);
 string JsonDB = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);

 MyDB myDB = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDB>(JsonDB);
```

Here is the object class (Tag and Astro are enums):

```
public class MyDB
{
    public string Version;
    public DateTime Date;
    public List<PhotoSpot_v0_1> Lista_v0_1;
}

public enum version
{
    v0_1
}

public class PhotoSpot_v0_1
{
    public int      ID          { get; set; }
    public string   Title       { get; set; }
    public string   Description { get; set; }
    public int      Rating      { get; set; }
    public bool     Reminder    { get; set; }
    public bool     Toast       { get; set; }

    private double   Latitude   { get; set; }
    private double   Longitude  { get; set; }
    private double   Altitude   { get; set; }

    public Geopoint Geopoint    { get; set; }
    public Geopoint Landmark    { get; set; }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get; set; }

    public string MainTag { get; set; }


    public version Version { get; set; }
    public Landmark_v0_1             Landmarks    { get; set; }
    public List<Image_v0_1>          Images       { get; set; }
    public List<URL_v0_1>            URLs         { get; set; }
    public List<globalVars.Tag>      Tags         { get; set; }
    public List<Date_v0_1>           Dates        { get; set; }

    public bool Downloaded { get; set; }
    public bool Exportable { get; set; }
}

public class Landmark_v0_1
{
    public bool             freeLandmark  { get; set; }
    public string           Title         { get; set; }
    private double          Latitude      { get; set; }
    private double          Longitude     { get; set; }
    private double          Altitude      { get; set; }
    public globalVars.Astro Astro         { get; set; }
}

public class Image_v0_1
{
    public string imageURI { get; set; }
    public bool   isDownloaded { get; set; }
}

public class URL_v0_1
{
    public string sURL { get; set; }
}

public class Tag_v0_1
{
    //public string TagName { get; set; }
    public globalVars.TagImageURL TagName { get; set; }
}

public class Date_v0_1
{

    private double DateStart;
    private double DateEnd;

    public DateTime DateTimeStart()
    {
        return CoreTime.JDToDateTime(DateStart);
    }

    public DateTime DateTimeEnd()
    {
        return CoreTime.JDToDateTime(DateEnd);
    }

    public void SetDateTimeStart(DateTime dt)
    {
        DateStart = CoreTime.DateTimeToJD(dt);
    }

    public void SetDateTimeEnd(DateTime dt)
    {
        DateEnd = CoreTime.DateTimeToJD(dt);
    }


}
```

I've checked that the Json string, before writing, after writing and when read are the same. Here it is if it's helpful. If something more is needed I'll post it.

```
   {
  "Version": "v0_1",
  "Date": "2020-01-08T10:49:04.6992512+01:00",
  "Lista_v0_1": [
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Title": "Abadi gaztelua",
      "Description": "",
      "Rating": 0,
      "Reminder": false,
      "Toast": false,
      "Geopoint": {
        "Position": {
          "Latitude": 43.380954170570355,
          "Longitude": -1.7520569699123154,
          "Altitude": 87.749645113013685
        },
        "AltitudeReferenceSystem": 2,
        "GeoshapeType": 0,
        "SpatialReferenceId": 4326
      },
      "Landmark": null,
      "TimeZone": {
        "Id": "Romance Standard Time",
        "DisplayName": "(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris",
        "StandardName": "Romance Standard Time",
        "DaylightName": "Romance Daylight Time",
        "BaseUtcOffset": "01:00:00",
        "SupportsDaylightSavingTime": true
      },
      "MainTag": "Monument",
      "Version": 0,
      "Landmarks": {
        "freeLandmark": false,
        "Title": null,
        "Astro": 0
      },
      "Images": [],
      "URLs": [],
      "Tags": [],
      "Dates": [],
      "Downloaded": false,
      "Exportable": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how does MyDB class looks like ? could you please share the code for MyDB

Comment: How can we possibly help if you haven't shown us the exact exception message or what `MyDB` looks like?

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the `MyDB` class, it's impossible to help you. Also, we shouldn't be doing the legwork here. You can further investigate _which_ field is causing the issues by trying to convert simpler objects (i.e. only with the first field, then the first two fields, then ...) until you stumble on the field that can't be converted. I suggest you come back to us once you at least know which field is failing, so you can provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to work with.

Comment: @DavidG The only error/exception message I have from the Output window is what I have posted:

exception 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

I don't have more clues...

Comment: Please spend some time making a question we can actually answer. First of all, this is not your actual class because it has a typo and cannot compile. Secondly you have not given us all the supporting classes. Thirdly, and I will say this again - you have not given us the full exception message. For example, if you use this code that you have given us, it will say `SerializationException: Member 'AdjustmentRules' was not found.`

Comment: @DavidG Sorry for the typo, but I don't feel it's so important that a parentesis is inserted when copying and pasting code... You're right that I didn't give all the supporting classes, my bad. And finally, I don't have, really, more info about the exception. The debug output window in VS2015 there isn't more info about that. I can post the scrrenshot if it helps.

Comment: @Flater I found the origin of the problems following your idea. Geopoint and TimeZoneInfo are giving me problems. Maybe because they're .NET based classes or partial sealed or something like that?

Comment: Every Exception in .NET comes with more information than just the type, at the very least there is a message and a stack trace. If you're only outputting the type then you need to fix that so you can understand the problem. Learn how to debug please.

Answer (score 1):

I think your class is not proper. I tried your code and it's working.

```
string filepath = "../../../json.txt";
            var test =  File.ReadAllText(filepath);
            Example myDB = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(test);
```

pl check your following class as per your json

```
public class Position
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Altitude { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geopoint
    {
        public Position Position { get; set; }
        public int AltitudeReferenceSystem { get; set; }
        public int GeoshapeType { get; set; }
        public int SpatialReferenceId { get; set; }
    }

    public class TimeZone
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string StandardName { get; set; }
        public string DaylightName { get; set; }
        public string BaseUtcOffset { get; set; }
        public bool SupportsDaylightSavingTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Landmarks
    {
        public bool freeLandmark { get; set; }
        public object Title { get; set; }
        public int Astro { get; set; }
    }

    public class ListaV01
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public bool Reminder { get; set; }
        public bool Toast { get; set; }
        public Geopoint Geopoint { get; set; }
        public object Landmark { get; set; }
        public TimeZone TimeZone { get; set; }
        public string MainTag { get; set; }
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public Landmarks Landmarks { get; set; }
        public IList<object> Images { get; set; }
        public IList<object> URLs { get; set; }
        public IList<object> Tags { get; set; }
        public IList<object> Dates { get; set; }
        public bool Downloaded { get; set; }
        public bool Exportable { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDB
    {
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public IList<ListaV01> Lista_v0_1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The MyDB class and its subclasses are what they are. TimeZone, Geopoint and Position are defined already in .NET, so I don't see why I need to code them again. 
Landmark also is a subclass and it's not what you proposed there.

Comment: @ImanolZubiaurre , can you share your  namespace for this. i will try for it. b'cz your class and json not matched

Comment: For position and Geopoint I think the namespace is Windows.Devices.Geolocation.

Comment: and timezoneinfo ?

Comment: "Version": 0 => in your class it's define under class ..this wrong it should be integer

Comment: TimeZoneInfo is under System. It's a basic class.